# Clickable transparent lines are impossible in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, line, transparency, patch

So I have 3 lines (technically patches) that have some transparency enabled. These lines were generated by the patchline FEX submission. The FEX entry works great by making patches seem like lines by adding a NaN to the end of the data so it doesn't create a big black patch between the end points of my line.

My lines looks like this

```
__        __
  \      /
_  \    /  _
 \  \__/  /
  \______/
```

The patch extends from the left end point to the right end point in a straight line across the top and then follows the line on the bottom. The actual patch is hidden (not drawn) though so all the user sees is the lines

The problem is if I wanted to click the bottom hump of the top line, it acts like I clicked the bottom line because it is part of that patch.

I have thought of a couple of workarounds and was hoping you guys could point out flaws or add ideas I might have missed with my workarounds.

Workaround #1

Ideally, I would create an actual line (line series obj.) over the transparent lines. I would turn hittest off on the patches and I would make the actual line invisible, but turn hittest on. The problem I am 99% sure exists is that if visibilty is off, you can't click the object. If anybody has a work around to that issue (documented or otherwise), that would be great.

Workaround #2

Turn the patchline hittest property to off. Make mock line objs. that follow the patchline coords. and have a line width very very small so as to make the line ideally pretty much invisible and have hit test clicks point to these lines instead. Has anybody tried something like this before? (I'm at work and can't try it now)

Workaround #3

NOTE THAT I REALLY DONT WANT TO DO THIS It is of course possible to turn off hittest for the patch/line objs and use the axes buttondown to figure out what patch obj (just the line part) it was closest to.

Once again, any insight would be much appreciated either about my possible work arounds, the situation in general, etc.

Thanks, Shaun

Comment: Create two patches, one for upper line and one for bottom one? If I am missing something, please provide exmple code and link to FEX submission.

Comment: Here is the FEX entry: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36953-patchline/content/patchline.m

And the problem is I DO have multiple patches, and they overlap in some cases. ..Although I wonder if I could bring one to the top more than the other ones..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be illustrated with two line-thick patches, one of which is NOT parallel to the axes:

```
patch([2 8 8],[5 10 10],'w','EdgeColor','b','EdgeAlpha',0.4,'LineWidth',3)
patch([2 8 8],[4  4  4],'w','EdgeColor','r','EdgeAlpha',0.4,'LineWidth',3)
xlim([0 10])
ylim([3 11])
```

You cannot select but those lines which are parallel to one of the axes.

- Workaround #1: impossible.
- Workaround #2: quite visible, why would you need transparent lines then?
- Workaround #3: the only way...

Workaround alternative: submit to the TMW a technical request to improve clickability of patches.

Comment: THere is never just one way in MATLAB ;) I did figure out how to do it (see my answer) but I accepted yours as a thank you and also because I can't accept my own for two days haha

Comment: If you were to look at the FEX entry, you will see that it is by no means a patch in the traditional sense, it is by appearance the exact same as a line series object (with the option for transparency) , but behind the scenes it is still a full patch object. This last part was the issue because even though it looks like a line, the buttondown was still hitting the real behind the scenes patch

Comment: My example creates lines with patch objects and there is no way you can click the body of the patch because it 0 thick. Nonetheless, the horizontal line can be selected while the oblique one cannot. Therefore, even if you sort the plotting order, oblique sections of your line will not react to the click.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you trying to select the body of the patch? and what exactly is the "body", just the filled area? If that's the case, we have polar opposite problems I think haha

Comment: @Shaun314 Please, run my example above.

Comment: Oleg, I see what you are saying now, what bizarre behavior! I would definitely recommend using the patchline FEX entry I posted a link to (<http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36953-patchline/content/patchline.m>), and then keep in mind what I found out about the overlap issue, but I think using patchline would be more robust and intuitive for you to use.

Comment: `patchline()` creates an invisible body with the NaN. If you try `patchline([2; 3; 4],[1; 2; 3],'edgecolor','r');
xlim([1,5]);
ylim([0,4]);` you will notice that if you click anywhere on the imaginary upper right triangle which has the line on the hypotenuse, then the line gets selected. I am not sure I like it.

Answer (score 0):

Oleg, your initial post somehow inspired me to come up with my elegant solution. (Don't ask me how, just accept my "thank you" haha)

The elegant solution to my problem required me to go beyond patch properties and turn to the axes child order. Under the assumption that none of the lines would intersect each other, I was able to plot them in a order where the bottom one was first, then the second lowest, etc. until I got to the top (effectively rearranging child order).

If anybody else stumbles upon this, what you can do (assuming your lines don't intersect) is to sort the first Y (or whatever values) to go from lowest to highest (in this case) in your plot, and make sure your sort function returns the indicies.

I don't have my computer in front of me, but what you end up doing is effectively making an acontinuous for loop, looping through the indicies.

something like:

```
for i=[6 2 5 4 1 3]

  plot(X(:,i),Y(:,i))

end
```

Where the 6th column was my lowest data, 2nd column was second lowest on plot, etc.

Comment: I dont fully understand the issue here, but you can manipulate the Z-order using `uistack` function

Comment: I think that could have helped as well, thanks for pointing that out!